# Импорт экзел файла в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, excel, импорт

Как импортировать экзел(xls) файл в postgresql. Использую просто терминал(не использую ГУИ программы вроде pgadmin). Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Сохранить xls-файл в формат CSV
2. Выполнить в psql команду `COPY some_table FROM '/path/to/file.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;`

Comment: Сначала в постгре нужно создать таблицу или после этой команды она сама создастся ?

Comment: Таблица должна существовать.

Comment: Где существовать? Я имею ввиду, должен ли я создать таблицу прежде чем импортировать из экзела?

Comment: В базе данных. Да, должны.